# Why does this Albacore msbuild task fail to copy this web project assembly?

Tags: msbuild, rake, albacore

We're using Rake with Albacore for our build and deploy process in TeamCity. But, my latest solution has problems when compiling. When I run the `msbuild` task, I get this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(60,3): error MSB3021: Unable to
>    copy file "bin\admin.web.dll" to "C:/src/Trunk/admin/output/_PublishedWebsites\web\bin\admin.web.dll". Could not find file 'bin\admin.web.
>   dll'.

The build output path for the website project is set to `bin\`. And it copies fine when built in Visual Studio. But, building through Rake doesn't work. My compilation ruby file has the `:outdir` set to `'output/_PublishedWebsites'` and it copies fine for all my other solutions.

It's an edge case but it's causing me pain - anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help but it isn't anything specific to the msbuild task. The solution had 3 web projects in it & one of them had the bin directory included in the solution in VS. All I needed to do was exclude from the solution & the build & publish works fine - no more locking.

Comment: glad to hear you figured it out. :)

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer to this problem? how exactly did you exclude from the solution? why was the bin folder included? i am having the same problem and cant figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

whats the full msbuild command that gets executed?

**Edit** pretty sure its a path issue. I use

```
/p:WebProjectOutputDir: /output
/p:OutDir: /output/bin
```

If you post the ms build command, or at least the albacore config it would be much easier to help ;)

What project are you building? what dependencies does it have?

Comment: we are using albacore, just looked at the source & I think it's generating it correctly http://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/blob/master/lib/albacore/msbuild.rb